# How to Change Color of a cell in excel from Silverlight using Com AutomationFactory

Tags: silverlight, excel, colors, comautomationfactory

Hi
Im using AutomationFactory from silverlight to create and manipulate Exel worksheet.
And I want to change Color of a cell. If I understand correctly I must change this property

```
cell.Interior.Color =
```

However I want to change it to MyObject.Color (whitch is of tzpe Color)
MSDN Says i should use RGB function to assign cell.Interior.Color
But there is no RGB function in silverlight!?
How to change Color to something cell.Interior.Color will understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made RGB function..

```
internal static int RGB(Color color)
        {
            string hexaString=color.B.ToString("X2") + color.G.ToString("X2") + color.R.ToString("X2");
            int rgb = int.Parse(hexaString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            return rgb;
        }
```